# Simple Javascript Conflicting with Mailchimp Signup Form

Tags: javascript, mailchimp

So I have a simple Accordion On one of my pages, I need to be able to have a Mailchimp Signup form embedded inside the accordion. The accordion works perfectly until I embed the mailchimp form, then it no longer expands to actually show the form inside the accordion. I'm assuming the two java scripts are conflicting with each other so I'm just wondering if there is a simple code change I can make to one of the Javascript (or both) to make them function correctly together. here are the two javascripts

Accordion Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($) {
$('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){

  //Expand or collapse this panel
  $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

  //Hide the other panels
  $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

});
});
</script>
```

Mailchimp Javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script><script type='text/javascript'>(function($) {window.fnames = new Array(); window.ftypes = new Array();fnames[4]='MMERGE4';ftypes

[4]='text';fnames[5]='MMERGE5';ftypes[5]='text';fnames[3]='MMERGE3';ftypes[3]='radio';fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';fnames[2]='MMERGE2';ftypes[2]='phone';fnames[6]='MMERGE6';ftypes[6]='address';fnames[7]='MMERGE7';ftypes[7]

='text';fnames[8]='MMERGE8';ftypes[8]='radio';fnames[9]='MMERGE9';ftypes[9]='text';fnames[10]='MMERGE10';ftypes[10]='radio';fnames[11]='MMERGE11';ftypes[11]='radio';fnames[12]='MMERGE12';ftypes[12]='radio';fnames[13]='MMERGE13';ftypes

[13]='text';}(jQuery));var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me. And take in mind I am not that familiar with javascript but I am very proficient in html, css, php, and shipify's Liquid.

Comment: Have you [checked the console for errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/hello-world/714/using-console-log)

Comment: Could you provide the relevant html too?

Answer (score 0):

To exactly know what the conflict is, you need to share the console error so that we can check.

Alternatively, if you are proficient on HTML and CSS, you can create the form in html rather than using the embedded script, you just need to add the form action as the url that you got on the above script, and add the fields name and id with the merge field name.

Above solution is just a viable suggestion, if you want to continue with the including of the embedded form, you need to share the console errors that will make it easy to debug.